# How to map an indexed collection into a List using JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have the following table structure:

```
Table: PARENT
 ID NUMBER
 NAME VARCHAR

Table: CHILDREN

 PARENT_ID NUMBER,
 FIELD NUMBER,
 VALUE VARCHAR
```

What would be the right approach to map this into the following structure?

```
class Parent {
  int id;

  String name;

  /* MAPPING HERE, where FIELD is the list's index number */
  List<String> children; // <-- Preferably

  /* OR */

  /* MAPPING HERE, where FIELD is the key */
  Hashtable<Integer,String> children;

}
```

I've already set it up to work with the hashtable version using this annotation:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "CHILDREN",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="PARENT_ID"))
@MapKeyColumn(name = "FIELD")
@Column(name = "VALUE")
```

But it throws an error when VALUE is null. Because Hashtable won't allow null values. I tried HashMap but I get this error.

```
The attribute is of type [class java.util.HashMap] but the mapping uses transparent indirection (lazy loading), requiring it to be a superclass of [IndirectMap].
```

Using EclipseLink.

** Edit:

Assuming data looks like this:

```
CHILDREN
PARENT_ID, FIELD, VALUE
        1,     0, "value 0"
        1,     1, NULL
        1,     2, "value 2"
```

Then my List should look like:

```
 [ "value 0", NULL, "value 2 ]
```

Or my hashtable:

```
0: "value 0"
1: null  (or no-entry)
2: "value 2"
```

Comment: why do you want to map as map? how does it make sense? what will be the key in the map?

Comment: I would like FIELD to be the index in the list, or the key in the hashtable/map. With VALUE being the items in the list or the values in the hashtable.

Comment: FIELD looks like it is just an order column - have you checked out the OrderColumn and tried using it with the ElementCollection with a List type? https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OrderColumn.html

Comment: I thought about that. But if there's a gap in the records then the values will be placed in the wrong slot. If FIELD 1 record is missing then "value 2" will be placed in slot index 1. I was hoping there'd be something that could do a more direct mapping.

Comment: How is a "gap" defined in the java model then? You store a null in the List?

Comment: I mean in the database, for a given parent id, doesn't have a full sequence of field IDs. Like if parent id 2, has the following field records 0, 1, 2, 4, 5. The value stored in Field 4 would become item index 3 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array or a regular List, with the annotation @OneToMany above the list of children in Parent. When you will launch tour code it should create a table to make limk between parents and children.

Comment: But how do I ensure the VALUE gets placed in the list according to the position in FIELD number?

Comment: when you will build a parent, u will first build the children like this : children1 = new children("Jonh"), the id can be auto genrated with this annotation above attribute ID @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO). then children2=new children("Jack"). then you will build the parent : parent1=new Parent(Georges, [children1,children2]) and jpa will automaticly associate in a table the parent id to both of children id. is that clear for you ?

Comment: If you mean FIELD should be autogenerated that won't work for me. Every field id has meaning and each value belongs to a specific field.

Comment: the id is your primary key no ? so u don't really care of the value, you just need this field to be unique am I right ?

Comment: FIELD 0 would be Address for example, while FIELD 1 would be zip code or something. So for all Parent objects, there would be a fixed number of values and their position in the list or field key is meaningful.

Comment: then you should describe your parent class using an ID field (autogenerated), one field address String and one field zipcode Int

Comment: The example here is a simplified version of the problem I'm trying to resolve. In my actual problem there are different types of Parent and field 0 will mean one thing in Parent Type 1 but something different in Parent Type 2. But that's not necessary to this problem.

Comment: yes i get that, the thing is, it's a real bad idea to use the ID field to for 2 purposes, just create a field for the ID and other fields for what you wanna do/comapre etc...

Comment: To elaborate further, in my application Parent is really a form/questionnaire. There are many types of forms that have questions in common and those are stored as Parent object properties like you suggest. But there are many questions that are unique to each form and it wouldn't be feasible to create a property and DB entry for each one. So field 23 might be "How much money do you have?" for the Mortgage application form, but "Who is your next of kin?" on the Life Insurance form.

Comment: Maybe you can make an object formProperties in your Parent class to regroup each unique values and then u can have a single entry which regroup every other little informations.

Comment: I could solve my problem by creating a Child entity. Just seemed like an overkill entity to hold the same information the list or hashtable would. Hoping there was a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the Hashtable implementation to work, and avoid the null value problem by adding a null to empty string converter. So by the time the value is sent to the hashtable's put() it is an empty string and not a null. Like this:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "CHILDREN",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="PARENT_ID"))
@MapKeyColumn(name = "FIELD")
@Column(name = "VALUE")
@Converter(converterClass = NullEmptyStringConverter.class, name = "nullEmptyStringConverter")
@Convert( "nullEmptyStringConverter" )
Hashtable<Integer,String> children;
```

With:

```
public class NullEmptyStringConverter implements Converter {

  @Override
  public Object convertDataValueToObjectValue(Object arg0, Session arg1) {
    return ( arg0 == null ? "" : arg0 );
  }
}
```

So not my preferred solution, but this seems to be the best I can get.

Answer (score 0):

The error message when using `HashMap` is self-explanatory. In order for the collection to be lazily-loaded, Hibernate needs to proxy it using a custom map implementation (`IndirectMap`). It cannot do it since you declared `children` to be of the concrete type `HashMap`, though.

The solution is not to force `children` to be a `Hashmap`. Use a `Map` instead.